# Storing files on S3 using CollectionFS

Tags: meteor, amazon-s3, collectionfs

I am trying to use Meteor, CollectionFS and S3 to store files. I setup my bucket, set the key ID and secret to, and configure store.S3 as follows:

```
var fileStore = new FS.Store.S3('files', {
        bucket: Meteor.settings.public.storage.bucket
});
```

However, whenever I try to upload a file, I receive:

```
Error storing file to the files store: The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.
```

Is there any way to set the signature version/authorization mechanism using CollectionFS?

Comment: Use `Meteor-Files`. It is well documented. Here is the S3 integration documentation: https://github.com/VeliovGroup/Meteor-Files/wiki/AWS-S3-Integration

Answer (score 1):

Ostrio:files is the best and up to date library for that. It is fully documented and very well supported and you will see that when you look at the response time on their git page. I have an implementation of camera to S3 with that so if you get stuck I can probably help you and as I said the support on the git directly is amazing.

Comment: Thank you very much Paul. I will give it a try!